# Android creating a folder using shell or command within app

Tags: android, android-studio

I know that there are other ways to create folder in  android I am doing this for learning purpose.

Here is my code

```
val cmd="mkdir -p /external_files/hell"
            val process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
            var line="d"
            while (line!=null) {
                line=bufferedReader.readLine()
                if(line!=null)
                Log.d("tag", line)
            }
```

**I am testing in  real oreo device. Folder is not created and I get this error.**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testterminal, PID: 8516
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: bufferedReader.readLine() must not be null
        at com.example.testterminal.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:28)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6304)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24803)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :-

```
val dir = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "/Your Directory")
if(!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs()
}
```